# I need help formatting my laptop

Tags: windows-7, boot, formatting, partition-recovery

I am currently using a Packard Bell Easynote LJ75.

This laptop is running several partitions.

[image]

My laptop was running fine with Windows 7 installed on `E:`, and `C:` being used to store all apps and data. These were the default "factory" settings.

However, last week the system stopped working properly, so I decided to re-install Windows 7 on `C:` since the one on `E:` was "corrupted" or not working properly.

Now I have two OS and I boot my computer using a USB drive (otherwise I would get the `bootmgr missing` error on startup).

However, I would like to know what happens if I format `E:` and install Windows 7 there again. Is that possible? Could I format `C:` after this and have my computer with just one OS and running the same way as it was when it came out of the factory?

Finally, I just downloaded Windows 7 Home Premium x64 (64-bit) from [Digital River](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/). I burned it on a DVD using the "[Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool)" to make a bootable DVD.

Am I ready to format `E:`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would format all of those partitions and make a fresh install of Win7 on drive C. I was using two OS in different partitions in the past but using drive C is the most efficient way...

To get rid of unwanted OS on the boot menu you should delete OS entry from the boot menu by using

1. Run → msconfig → boot then delete OS on E drive
2. Format E drive
3. Continue using Win7 on C drive (or make a fresh install on C)
4. If I were you I would not use E for win7 in any situation

**Do not forget to assign undeleted OS as default after deleting any OS.**

Comment: So would you live the E: partition with the corrupted Win 7 OS? You mean format all partitions and merge them into C:? Why not having a separate partition with windows 7 on it like I have right now? Isn't this more secure?

Comment: 1-Run > msconfig > boot then delete OS on E drive
2-Format E drive
3-Continue using Win7 on C drive (or make a fresh install on C)
4-If I were you I would not use E for win7 in any situation.

Comment: why wouldn't you use win 7 on E: in any situation? This was how my laptop came by default.

Comment: one of the reasons is the default file adresses of softwares that you will install. So it makes easier to use C.

Comment: when I run "msconfig > boot" there is nothing to select there :S

Comment: this means that you have only one OS on your laptop.
Can't you see any OS on that list? You should see at least one OS there.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/PDlSF.png) is all I see.

Comment: no, this is not normal, maybe you deleted all entries. You should have left the OS that you would like to keep.